# Can I call a constructor of a subclass from the parent class?

Tags: php, class, object

In the below code, can `foo`'s constructor invoke `child1` or `child2`'s constructor?

```
class child1 extends foo{
  function child1(){
    do_stuff();
  }
}

class child2 extends foo{
  function child2(){
    do_stuff();
  }
}

class foo{
  function foo(){
    // run child1, child2 etc... ? is it possible?
  }
}

new foo();
```

Comment: Vice versa - you can call parent methods in extended class. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before we discuss the how to do of your question, I think we should clarify a bit on the OOP you are showing in your code here.

In your example, class foo is the base class and would have functionality, properties common to all types of foo.  For example, Foo might be a tree.  All trees have a trunk, roots, branches, and process sunlight into energy.

Now your child1 and child2 classes would be decendants of foo and have specific things that are in addition to or different from foo.  For example, child1 might be an Oak which "is a" tree but adds the leaf property and the acorn property and the hibernate property.

Child1 and Child2 know everything there is to know about foo but foo has no idea the child1 and child2 exist.

Now if I understand what you are trying to do, you would implement that by instantiating your child1 and child2 classes and invoking whatever methods you needed on those objects from within another class or method/function.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can only access classes from a parent class not the other way around. The parent doesn't know that those child classes exist.

If you explain the use case of what you're trying to do someone may be able to suggest a better approach.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean "functions" in place of "classes" in the first sentence?